# How to correctly dispose a child UIViewController?

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.ios

First I remove the child `UIViewController` from the container with

```
private void removeFromContainer(UIViewController viewController)
{
    viewController.WillMoveToParentViewController (null);
    viewController.View.RemoveFromSuperview ();
    viewController.RemoveFromParentViewController ();
    viewController.DidMoveToParentViewController (null);
}
```

Then I want to dispose it

```
private void disposeChild(UIViewController viewController){
    if (viewController != null) {
        viewController.Dispose();
        viewController = null;
    }
}
```

If I try this

```
if (viewController.IsViewLoaded && viewController.View.Window != null && viewController.ParentViewController != null) {
    // ...
}
```

the app crashes with

> **System.ObjectDisposedException**
>   The object was used after being disposed.

From my standpoint the *viewController* should be null, but it seems it isn't.

How do I correctly dispose the child view controller?

Answer (score 0):

After I call *disposeChild()* I `null` out the variable. Seems that passing by reference doesn't occur. But I don't think that a copy is made. Perhaps one could exlain that ...